# Aligning glyphicons and logo on the nav bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[My navbar looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH6sP.png). There are two questions I have here.

Q1. I want to add a white border to my logo (extreme right). I've tried everything,including adding the  `filter:  drop-shadow(10px 10px 5px -5px white)` but somehow, nothing gets added to the image.

The HTML and CSS codes for the logo (on extreme left) and the glyphicon (extreme right) are as follows -

Logo HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
      </a>
```

Logo CSS

```
.navbar-brand img {

     width:60x;
     height:60px;
     position:relative;
     bottom:20px;
     object-fit:contain;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 5px -5px white);
    filter:  drop-shadow(10px 10px 5px -5px white); 

}
```

Q2. I want to align the glyphicon on the extreme right a bit to the top. I'v tried `

```
display:relative;`top:4px;`
```

but it doesn't do the trick. Any thoughts on that?

HTML glyphicon:

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> </span>  </a></li>
```

Thanks in advance for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Q1:**

It is possible to add a [border radius](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) to your styling:

```css
border: 1px solid white;
border-radius: 25px;
```

However, according to highest rated answer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/306279/im-looking-to-save-an-irregular-shaped-image-what-is-are-most-popular-formats) post, all images are saved in a width X height format, making it impossible to add a border like you are intending. You will need to manually add the border to your .png image, with Photoshop or some other program.

For **Q2:**

You want to add position [absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) to the CSS. So the code will look like this:

```css
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
```

Comment: The border property creates a rectangular border. What I'm looking for is a border which perfectly surrounds the PNG image.

Comment: If that is the case, add.a [border radius](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp). That will have the desired effect.

Comment: The position of the glyphicon is now correct, thank you for that! But the image is not a perfect rectangle or a square, it has it's own unique shape with empty spaces around  it. I want a border that exactly surrounds this shape. Is that possible, or do I need to add a border manually in the image using photoshop and then use it in CSS?

Comment: As far as I know  [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp) is the most detailed you can get with CSS.

Comment: OK, I did some more research and updated the answer.

Comment: Aaah, got it! Thanks a ton, I'll do so in Photoshop.